# data is not visible in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add dynamic row in jquery datatable. But the data is not visible in a grid. Here is my code.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.2/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>

<script>
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 "aoColumns": [{"title":"url","name":"url"},
             {"title":"authority","name":"authority"}],
 ordering: true,
 retrieve:true,
 "bJQueryUI": true,
 paging: false
 });  
</script>
```

I am adding row by using this code.

```
table.row.add({
                    "url":"www.example.com",
                    "authority":"99"
                    }).draw();
```

[image]
I am getting this error.

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: did you redraw the table? table.rows().invalidate().draw(false);

Comment: yeah, but still getting the same error

Comment: what table.rows()[0].length gives you?

Comment: To add row you should use fnAddData()

Comment: I think not he is using DataTable not datatable

Comment: I usually define the datatable with.DataTable({
                        data: _thelist you want,
                        responsive: true,
                        columns: [
                            { data: "url" },
                            { data: "authority" }]
                    });

Comment: @Anirudh: I am getting an error as TypeError: table.fnAddData is not a function after using fnAddData().

Comment: yea that function is for dataTable

Comment: I am using `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>`

Comment: Then below code will work for you.. Any ways i will add fnAddData() below , have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ... This may help you..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
var counter = 1;

$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add( [
        counter +'.1',
        counter +'.2',
        counter +'.3',
        counter +'.4',
        counter +'.5'
    ] ).draw( false );

    counter++;
} );

// Automatically add a first row of data

$('#addRow').click();
} );
```

If its dataTable then you can use fnAddData..

```
 var giCount = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnClickAddRow() {
 $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    giCount+".1",
    giCount+".2",
    giCount+".3",
    giCount+".4" ] );

giCount++;
}
```

Comment: The second solution works for me. Thanks for your help.